# Just need a variable, strong_params in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I would like to do something like:

```
class TestController < InheritedResources::Base

    def test_method
        self.var1 + self.var2
    end

  private

    def test_params
      params.require(:test).permit(:var1, :var2)
    end
end
```

Where in the view I could call from the built in controller index:

```
test.test_method
```

I've tried adding a create method to the controller as follows:

```
def create
    Test.create!(require(:test).permit(:var1, :var2, :test_method))
end
```

I've also tried updating the params directly:

```
 private

    def test_params
      params.require(:test).permit(:var1, :var2, :test_method)
    end
```

I've also tried making a helper method, but I knew that was doomed to fail because it wouldn't have access to `var1` and `var2`.

I guess I just don't understand two things: one how to make my `var1` and `var2` white-listed so I can use them, and more importantly how to add a method to my model using strong parameters, because `attr_accessible` doesn't work in my models anymore.

EDIT:

Let me rephrase a little, maybe it will help. I can get access to individual Test objects in my view with a simple call to `tests.each |test|` in the view. I just want to make methods that act on my already defined active record variables for that object, hence `var1` and `var2`. The problem is when I define a new method in my controller it is private to the object and I won't have access to it with a call from an instance of the object. Better yet, I would like to just be able to define a new variable, local to the object, that is created after it has propagated its other fields from the db.

EDIT2: I'm aware I'm probably missing the design pattern here. It can be hard to describe that I want X, when really I need Z. Thanks for the patience.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you trying to call a controller method from an instance of an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason for white-listing parameters that you'll directly use.
White-listing with strong parameters is useful only when you call function like ActiveRecord#update that simply take every key from the dictionary, so you can control with key you want to allow and which not.
In this case, just do:

```
class TestController < InheritedResources::Base
  def test_method
    @result = params[:var1] + params[:var2]
  end
end
```

And in your view, just print the `@result` variable wherever you want

```
<%= @result %>
```

This is the Rails way. You can of course call the variable as you want.
Helper methods are useful only for more complex cases.

Comment: I feel like this is the right track; however, I still cant use it for individual objects, like in `tests.each |test|`, `test.test_method` does not work. Really, I'd like to be able to define variables that are created at instance level after being filled by the db. Use them, then before sumbit or save convert back to db fields. etc. but first I have to be able to get access to those db fields at instance level, but since attr_asscessible doesnt work...

Comment: test_method is a Controller method, test is a model. You can't mix the 2 things... are var1 and var2 fields of Test class?

Comment: yes, `var1` and `var2` are part of the model. I understand you can't really mix them, but I don't have access to them in the model with `attr_accessible`, what am I supposed to do if I just want a regular old variable in my model that doesn't get filled by the db and I do stuff with it throughout my controller and render it in my view.

Comment: Just put `test_method` in your model and call `test.test_method` in your view. Can't see the problem. Methods are not private by default in models

Comment: Oh wow. Okay, that worked. I don't know why I didn't try that. Thanks.